# MySQL concatenation operator

Tags: mysql, sql, concatenation

I don't know concatenation operator for MySQL.

I have tried this code for concatenation:

```
SELECT vend_name || ' (' || vend_country || ')'
FROM Vendors
ORDER BY vend_name;
```

But it didn't work.  Which operator should I use to concatenate strings?

Comment: Today i have realized that something like "SELECT 'hello ' 'world' AS col1, ' from ' 'Mysql' AS col2     

....also works

Comment: @DiegoAndrésDíazEspinoza: That's "concatenation of adjacent string literals", isn't it?  That is, it works when you're concatenating two string literals (perhaps because they're too long to fit on one line).  Does it also work if you try to concatenate a column with a string literal, as in the question?  I'd expect that the answer is 'no'.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler yes, it is adjacent concatenation of string literal, that is why it was just a comment, not an answer. Attending to answers below it is not possible adjacent concatenation, it is just possible while using CONCAT.

Answer (score 60, accepted):

You were using ORACLE type of concatenation. MySQL's Should be

```
 SELECT CONCAT(vend_name, '(', vend_country, ')')
```

Call the `CONCAT()` function and separate your values with commas.

Answer (score 81):

`||` is the ANSI standard string concatenation operator, supported by most databases (notably [not MS SQL Server](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11404025/1157100)).  MySQL also supports it, but you have to [`SET sql_mode='PIPES_AS_CONCAT';`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/sql-mode.html#sqlmode_pipes_as_concat) or [`SET sql_mode='ANSI';`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/sql-mode.html#sqlmode_ansi) first.

Answer (score 14):

MySQL CONCAT function is used to concatenate two strings to form a single string. Try out following example:

```
mysql> SELECT CONCAT('FIRST ', 'SECOND');
+----------------------------+
| CONCAT('FIRST ', 'SECOND') |
+----------------------------+
| FIRST SECOND               |
+----------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

To understand CONCAT function in more detail consider an employee_tbl table which is having following records:

```
mysql> SELECT CONCAT(id, name, work_date)
    -> FROM employee_tbl;
+-----------------------------+
| CONCAT(id, name, work_date) |
+-----------------------------+
| 1John2007-01-24             |
| 2Ram2007-05-27              |
| 3Jack2007-05-06             |
| 3Jack2007-04-06             |
| 4Jill2007-04-06             |
| 5Zara2007-06-06             |
| 5Zara2007-02-06             |
+-----------------------------+
```

Comment: Is mysql don't have any operator for that

Answer (score 5):

Whats good about using `concat` is that you can pass different data type columns and concat string representations

```
 SELECT concat('XXX',  10.99, 'YYY', 3, 'ZZZ', now(3)) as a;
```

Output

> a
>   -----
>   XXX10.99YYY3ZZZ2018-09-21 15:20:25.106

Answer (score 2):

Simply you can use `CONCAT` keyword to concatenate the Strings..
You can use it like

```
SELECT CONCAT(vend_name,'',vend_country) FROM vendors ORDER BY name;
```

Comment: What is the use of adding an empty string in between?

Comment: How does adding an empty string (nothing) improve or even change the result? I'm missing something...

Answer (score -1):

You have to set pipes as concat every time before you run a query using pipes as a concatenate operator.