# Concatenate string with field value in MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, sql, concatenation

I have the need to concatenate a string with a field value in a MySQL query in order to LEFT JOIN two tables.

Table one has a column called "category_id" with numeric values, such as 61, 78, 94 and such.

Table two has a column called "query" which refers to a request route mechanism, and it has values such as "product_id=68", "category_id=74", "manufacturer_id=99" and so on.

So in my query I require to join the tables when ever a concatenated string derived from a set string and the value of the "category_id" column matches the query field.

My SQL statement is currently:

```
SELECT * FROM tableOne 
LEFT JOIN tableTwo
ON tableTwo.query = 'category_id=' + tableOne.category_id
```

I have tried using the || operator instead of the + operator, but still no luck. Is it possible to do this in MySQL, or have I jumped the gun here?

Answer (score 103, accepted):

Have you tried using the [concat()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/string-functions.html#function_concat) function?

```
ON tableTwo.query = concat('category_id=',tableOne.category_id)
```

Comment: Perfect! I had tried using `CONCAT_WS('=', 'category_id', tableOne.category_id)`, but it seems that was the wrong function entirely!

Thank you very much!

Comment: This is fine. But how can I concatenate on both side of field. like adding quotes on both sides of menuid for eg: "menuid1".?

Comment: Since concat() accepts an arbitrary number of arguments (http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/string-functions.html#function_concat), you should be able to concat('"',table.column,'"');

Answer (score 10):

```
SELECT ..., CONCAT( 'category_id=', tableOne.category_id) as query2  FROM tableOne 
LEFT JOIN tableTwo
ON tableTwo.query = query2
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, this is an elegant solution!

Answer (score 9):

Here is a great answer to that:

`SET sql_mode='PIPES_AS_CONCAT';`

Find more here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/24777235/4120319

Here's the full SQL:

```
SET sql_mode='PIPES_AS_CONCAT';

SELECT * FROM tableOne 
LEFT JOIN tableTwo
ON tableTwo.query = 'category_id=' || tableOne.category_id;
```

Answer (score 3):

MySQL uses [CONCAT()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_concat) to concatenate strings

```
SELECT * FROM tableOne 
LEFT JOIN tableTwo
ON tableTwo.query = CONCAT('category_id=', tableOne.category_id)
```