# SQL - Get records from one table that aren't "LIKE" in another table

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two tables:
tables: **products** and **posts**

table **products** has field **model** with values "AH0002", "O-PO-201", "O-PO-304" etc.
table **posts** has field **post_title** with values like "Product AH0002 is the best", "Red O-PO-201 is really good".

What I need is to display products rows where their name doesn't appear in posts table (in post_title field).

How to do it in mysql?

Comment: Can you show what you've got so far?  You'll need a `like` condition as well as a `where not exists` condition for sure.  Beyond that, we'll really need to see what you already have.

Comment: @user2366842 you don't NEED a not exists subquery, and it may not perform as well as other options, ie. an outer join or a not in subquery

Comment: True, I suppose I jumped the gun on that.....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
select pr.*
  from products pr
  left join posts po
    on post_title like concat('%', pr.model, '%')
 where post_title is null
```

The above assumes mysql syntax, it will vary slightly by database.

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/ec9d6/5)

Comment: I had to add only CONVERT to pr.model but it work like a charm. When I remove where clause than I get products that are in both tables ;)

Comment: @Ryan convert would be needed if the field model is a different data type than post_title. Yes the where clause is filtering in on products with no associated posts, the left outer join to the posts table is what allows nulls, so by allowing nulls you can filter in on nulls in the WHERE clause. Also if you wanted all posts w/ no products (the other way around), you can change "left join" to "right join" and change "where post_title is null" to "where pr.model is null"

Answer (score 1):

I think you want something like this:

```
SELECT p.*
  FROM products p
 WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM posts WHERE post_title LIKE '%' + p.model + '%')
```

This syntax assumes Microsoft SQL Server.

For MySQL, just change the LIKE clause to be LIKE CONCAT('%', p.model, '%')

Comment: The above syntax is for SQL Server

Comment: In MySQL `+` doesn´t work to concatante strings - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19261760/concatenate-string-with-field-value-in-mysql

Comment: Use `Concat` instead - concat('%',p.model,'%')

Comment: As already stated, the above SQL is for SQL Server, and works there.  For MySQL just adjust the syntax as required.

Comment: But it could work in mySQL and attends to the OP requirements. Why not fix the code? It is very simple to do.

Answer (score 0):

Using `LIKE`

```
select *
from products A
where model not in (
   select model
   from posts
   inner join products
      on post_title like concat('%',model,'%')
)
```

Look at the [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/ec9d6/9/0)