# Update All Rows in DataBase with a hash value

Tags: php, mysql, database

Using Php & MySQL, I want to Update All Rows of a Particular Column in The DataBase,

Eg. : in The Column "Name" there is a Row which Contains "MyName",

Here is my Scheme I am Trying To Achieve & The Logic:

1. Loop The DataBase
2. Get the Current Value for each rows & hash it with hash('...', value);

Get the existing values for each rows & hash it & Update, This is How I want to Update The Full DataBase,

How can I achieve this ?

Comment: issue an update statement with no where clause. `Update myTable set colX=func(something in here with colX)`

Comment: what are you actually trying to change? are you trying to change every instance of `MyName` to be some other value?

Comment: @Drew update statements without a where on the PK are considered invalid updates.. MySQL allows it to proceed where all other SQL languages blow up. wouldn't recommend that

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Concatenate string with field value in MySQL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19261760/concatenate-string-with-field-value-in-mysql)

Comment: for how long? hashing it wont last forever. and will cause performance issues in memory

Comment: @JohnRuddell that is over-ride-able however you spell that word

Comment: Am I right in assuming that the question is how to call the hash function from a mysql update?

Comment: are you saying you want to hash the values and store them in a mysql table? if thats the case just make an archive table and archive your data that way. you can't query hash objects in mysql except selecting it out.

Comment: is it safe to say that you have clear text and want a hash value? Is it safe to say that the clear text doesnt belong there but only the one-way hash value?

Comment: what i'm saying is hashing is used in programming languages to make things more efficient for that programming language when you want to do operations with it. SQL though hashing values provides no help at all. infact it makes it worse because its considered un normalized data... you want to archive it in another table with the same format

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First I must say that if you have non-sensitive data in a db, then the built-in mysql functions can give you results of hashes directly with update statements using just mysql.

This answer is not about that. It is about sensitive data, like passwords.

I gave you a link to a PHP `password_hash()` and `password_verify()` example.

Here is [That Link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32556010) again. That link to the left is for PDO. The following [Link Right Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33665819) is similar and for mysqli.

In the PDO link look at the line

```
$hp=password_hash($ctPassword,PASSWORD_DEFAULT); // hashed password, using
```

So let's say you have a column now with cleartext in it called `ctPassword`. You would `alter table` and add a new column for something like `hashedPassword`. Follow that link I provided, tweak accordingly, hash the values of `ctPassword` into `hashedPassword` with an update statement.

Then test it thoroughly. When all is right in the world, **drop** the `ctPassword` column and never use it again. **To be clear**, never store clear text passwords in databases. Store one-way hash values, and verify against them. The above links show how.

### Edit

Here is entirely from PHP where I think this needs to be driven from, as opposed to mysql hash functions, yuck. Afterall, you are using PHP, and it is there that their robust hashing and verifying is going to shine. Best practices in my opinion, whereas the mysql folks don't exactly spend the mental bandwidth on it. I am all for doing as much as possible in mysql. But never this topic, using hashes. Let PHP drive this one.

### Schema

```
create table sometable
(   id int auto_increment primary key,
    userName varchar(40) not null,
    ctPassword varchar(40) not null -- clear text password (means humans can read it, basically)
    -- note, not a great definition of ct but it implies it has not been hashed for safety
);

insert sometable(userName,ctPassword) values
('Brenda','I watch TV too much'),
('Drew','PatriotsWorldChamps'),
('stealth_guy','JFIDU&JF_Anchovies');
```

Along comes the notion, hey, I want safe hashes now. I might get hacked.

```
-- http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/alter-table.html
alter table sometable add column hashedPassword varchar(255);
-- now I have 4 columns, hashedPassword is currently nullable
show create table sometable; -- confirms this fact
```

PHP to loop thru and update a new column meant to clean up prior not having a hash concept (that I think we have all seen 1M times on the stack)

**PHP for patching:**

```
<?php
    // turn on error reporting, or wonder why nothing is happening at times
    mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);
    //mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ALL);
    error_reporting(E_ALL);
    ini_set("display_errors", 1);    // Begin Vault

    // credentials from a secure Vault, not hard-coded
    $servername="localhost";
    $dbname="login_system";
    $username="dbUserName";
    $password="dbPassword";
    // End Vault

    try {
        $db = new PDO("mysql:host=$servername;dbname=$dbname", $username, $password);
        $db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
        $db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES, false);
        $stmt = $db->prepare("select id,ctPassword from sometable");
        $stmt->execute();
        $stmt->bindColumn('id', $theId);        // bind the results into vars by col names
        $stmt->bindColumn('ctPassword', $cPassword);        // ditto

        // http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetch.php
        while ($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_BOUND)) {
            // as we loop thru here, the $theId and $cPassword variables will be auto-magically updated
            // for us because they have been bound as seen above
            $hPassword=password_hash($cPassword,PASSWORD_DEFAULT); // we now have a hashed password based on orig clear text one
            echo $cPassword . "   " . $hPassword . "<br>";
            // each time you run this with same data the hashes will be different due to changes in the salt
            // based on above PASSWORD_DEFAULT (look at manual page for password_hash)
            $sqlUpdate="UPDATE sometable set `hashedPassword`='$hPassword' where `id`=$theId";

            $db->query($sqlUpdate);
        }
        // .. other cleanup as necessary
    } catch (PDOException $e) {
        echo 'Connection failed: ' . $e->getMessage();
        exit();
    }
?>
```

Run the php script, verify results. Those are mine, yours *will* differ. Yours will even differ from yours if you run it again. Reason mentioned in the code.

```
select * from sometable;

+----+-------------+---------------------+--------------------------------------------------------------+
| id | userName    | ctPassword          | hashedPassword                                               |
+----+-------------+---------------------+--------------------------------------------------------------+
|  1 | Brenda      | I watch TV too much | $2y$10$pJ5maui2OlrIPAtISf4u2OqeqEXU9ycDpCNNpp6xDh1uzIv/6ybuW |
|  2 | Drew        | PatriotsWorldChamps | $2y$10$kHAKRSeHLi9cghPKTKox/.kXiFgq6ELWwExGcVvbf1yYprtTvi.Ba |
|  3 | stealth_guy | JFIDU&JF_Anchovies  | $2y$10$HOkBAkP7ZVIZ7NQB50aKAuhG5WjLHU9AtJCiY2E6h/M2YZuxc2l5K |
+----+-------------+---------------------+--------------------------------------------------------------+
```