# Does MySQL have a string contatenation operator, or must you use the > CONCAT() function?

Tags: mysql, concatenation

I was using `+` operator in MySQL to add string values

```
select id, first_name + '' + last_name as full_name
from account;
```

Would it work? If not then what is the alternative?

Comment: You have to use `CONCAT()`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MySQL concatenation operator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15631137/mysql-concatenation-operator)