# Truncated incorrect DOUBLE value when updating mysql column

Tags: mysql, sql-update

when trying to update my mysql database-column with following sql command

```
UPDATE db.vendor_horses SET image='{"images":["' + image  + '"]}';
```

I get following error:

```
UPDATE db.vendor_horses SET image='{"images":["' + image + '"]}'    Error Code: 1292. Truncated incorrect DOUBLE value: '{"images":["'  0.00028 sec
```

I can't figure out what's wrong..

Answer (score 1):

in mysql + is not valid concatenation sign. ([MySQL concatenation operator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15631137/mysql-concatenation-operator))
you should use [CONCAT](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html) function.

```
UPDATE db.vendor_horses SET image= CONCAT('{"images":["', image, '"]}';
```