# Mysql query based on empty and filled values

Tags: php, mysql

Two queries;

```
SELECT * 
FROM `products` 
WHERE product_type = "" AND product_description LIKE "%a%";
```

and

```
SELECT * 
FROM `products` 
WHERE product_type = 10 AND product_description LIKE "%a%";
```

The `product_type` value is full and works when it is correct (2md query).
But I also want it to work when the value is empty.

I also want a query to work like this, because there are a lot of columns;

```
SELECT * 
FROM `products` 
WHERE product_type = "" AND product_description LIKE "%a%" AND product_price = ""
```

Can you help me, please?

Comment: Yes, it's a search form. Dec. It will bring information according to the selected data there. Actually, I summarized the topic at the top.

Comment: Here's a good example of how to build up a search query dynamically - https://phpdelusions.net/mysqli_examples/search_filter

Comment: @user1191247  I want to do this in a single query. Isn't this possible?

Comment: I couldn't integrate this into the code. Can you integration?

Comment: You need a grouped Where clause containing OR. `I want to do this in a single query. Isn't this possible?`, what did you try so far?

Comment: @Adi It would be complicated to do as in the example with PHP. I wanted to do it in a single query. I think I actually solved this using LIKE.

Answer (score 2):

This is just builds up the `WHERE` clause dynamically, using the approach demonstrated in [the example](https://phpdelusions.net/mysqli_examples/search_filter) I suggested in the comments:

```php
<?php

$host = 'localhost';
$db   = '';
$user = '';
$pass = '';
$port = '3306';
$charset = 'utf8mb4';

$options = [
    PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE            => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION,
    PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE => PDO::FETCH_OBJ,
    PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES   => false,
];
$dsn = "mysql:host=$host;dbname=$db;charset=$charset;port=$port";
$pdo = new PDO($dsn, $user, $pass, $options);

// arrays to store the criteria
$conditions = [];
$parameters = [];

// conditional statements
if (!empty($_GET['product_type'])) {
    $conditions[] = 'product_type = ?';
    $parameters[] = $_GET['product_type'];
}

if (!empty($_GET['product_description'])) {
    $conditions[] = 'product_description LIKE ?';
    $parameters[] = '%' . $_GET['product_description'] . '%';
}

// the main query
$sql = 'SELECT * FROM products';

// if there are conditions, generate the WHERE clause
if ($conditions) {
    $sql .= ' WHERE '. implode(' AND ', $conditions);
}

// the usual prepare/execute/fetch routine
$stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql);
$stmt->execute($parameters);

var_dump($stmt->fetchAll());
```

Comment: I haven't tested this but it seems useful. Thank you for your answer.

Comment: @user please only answer well-asked questions.  This question's [mcve] is not clear and will not be a useful addition to Stack Overflow.

Answer (score -1):

You can write your query like this to get desire output,

SELECT *
FROM `products`
WHERE (product_type = "" || product_type = 10) AND product_description LIKE "%a%" AND product_price = "";

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/24777235/2943403