# What does SQL Select symbol || mean?

Tags: mysql, sql, oracle, ansi-sql

What does `||` do in SQL?

```
SELECT 'a' || ',' || 'b' AS letter
```

Comment: See also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1373238/string-concatenation-operator-in-oracle-postgres-and-sql-server

Comment: Did you try executing it?

Comment: It doesn't add anything in your example, but is helpful in other contexts, e.g. in `... WHERE Name LIKE '%' || :searched || '%'...`

Answer (score 96):

`||` represents string concatenation. Unfortunately, string concatenation is not completely portable across all sql dialects:

- ansi sql: `||` (infix operator)
- mysql: `concat` ( vararg function ). **caution**: `||` means 'logical or' ([It's configurable](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/sql-mode.html#sqlmode_pipes_as_concat), however; thanks to [@hvd](https://stackoverflow.com/users/743382/hvd) for pointing that out)
- oracle: `||` (infix operator), `concat` ( **caution**: function of arity 2 only ! )
- postgres:  `||` (infix operator)
- sql server: `+` (infix operator), `concat` ( vararg function )
- sqlite: `||` (infix operator)

hopefully the confusion is complete ...

Comment: [It's configurable in MySQL.](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/sql-mode.html#sqlmode_pipes_as_concat)

Comment: so MySQL is the only RDBMS where '||' is equivalent to logical OR?

Comment: Also [MariaDB](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/or/) treats `||` as logical OR by default, because MariaDB is a fork of MySQL. They have both changed enough since the fork that they should be considered different products, but they still share this behavior.

Answer (score 9):

SELECT 'a' || ',' || 'b' AS letter 
will combine a letter. 
The result become 'a,b'

Comment: the `||` operator concatenates strings

Answer (score 6):

It is a concat statement.  It will concatenate the two strings.

Here is a helpful post!

[What is the difference between "||" operator and concat function in Oracle?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11403931/what-is-the-difference-between-operator-and-concat-function-in-oracle)

Answer (score 5):

It's a concatenation operator.  So you would get 'a,b' from that.
I think `||` will work on *most* RDBMS's.  SQL Server requires the `+` operator (thanks to HVD for setting me straight!).

Comment: Microsoft SQL Server is one of the exceptions: it doesn't support `||`, and requires `+`.

Answer (score 5):

In Oracle, SQLite3, and MySQL, it concatenates strings. Please see the [Oracle documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/operators003.htm).  The [MySQL documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/sql-mode.html#sqlmode_pipes_as_concat).

Also, it's part of ANSI SQL, but [read this for more information](https://drupal.org/node/809698).

Answer (score 1):

in oracle its a shortcut for concatenate

http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/operators003.htm