# What does double bars (||) mean in SQL?

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to understand the following query:

`select count(distinct Name || '' || Surname) from PEOPLE;`

What does the double bars mean? What does this query do?

In MySQL:
`select  "aaaaa" || '' || "bbbbb";`

`+--------------------------+
| "aaaaa" || '' || "bbbbb" |
+--------------------------+
|                        0 |
+--------------------------+`

Comment: In Oracle DB two vertical bars concat strings. What db are you using?

Comment: This is string concatenation. You could run the query and see it for yourself.

Comment: When posting a question about SQL, it's usually relevant to also add a tag for the specific DBMS you're using, as syntax varies between them. (In this case, it appears you're using Oracle.)

Comment: @zvdh I'm using MySQL, and It doesn't seem string concatenationg

Comment: @Martin: I know, but the DBMS is relevant quite often; it's a good habit to get into. SQL Server uses '+' as a string concatenation operator, for instance. (Of course, the better solution would have been for the poster to simply run the query without the `count()` to see what it did in the first place instead of posting here.)

Comment: @Andreas, thank you, one of the answers says: `in MySQL || means 'logical or'`

Answer (score 62, accepted):

double bars are concatination:

```
select 'hello' || ' ' || 'world' from dual;
```

yields

```
'hello world'
```

Comment: Note you can also put a **column name** in the concat -- ```select 'hello' || col_1 || 'world' from dual;``` will concat the col_1 values from the table for the returned entries.

Comment: select 'hello' || ' ' || 'world' from dual;
=> 0

Comment: Note that this answer from the ansi standard. For `||`, mysql does not follow that standard. see https://stackoverflow.com/a/23372603/3430807 for details.