# catenate|| and %

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a simple sql:

```
select select t.x, '%' || t.x || '%' as c from t
```

The result is:

```
x c
a 0
b 0
```

That is, the catenatation results in 0, I don't know why

Comment: @TrebuchetMS `||` is ansi-standard. [See here.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24777235/3094533)

Comment: @TrebuchetMS thanks for the reply. It is not  duplicate of the link you mentioned,they are different question. concat() works for me, || is also mysql syntax, but doesn't work for %, don't know why

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What does double bars (||) mean in SQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23919378/what-does-double-bars-mean-in-sql)

Comment: @ZoharPeled my bad, wasn't aware that `||` could work with MySQL as well.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/23372603/5459839: in MySql, `||` is not (by default) string concatenation, but a logical OR.

Comment: Thanks all the guys for the reply, not aware of this before.

Comment: Because MySQL is the PHP of databases. A bit weird, but it's free, so everybody uses it anyway. :-p