# Meaning of `||` in an SQL SELECT statement

Tags: sql

I am modifying some SQL code and I have come across the statement:

```
SELECT 'pilot' || cast(id as string) AS id from ....
```

What does `||` do in this statement?

I thought it would replace `falsey` values by `'pilot'`; but that is not the case, it returns `NULL` values. There weren't any empty strings, but there were no rows with `'pilot'` either.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What does double bars (||) mean in SQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23919378/what-does-double-bars-mean-in-sql)

Comment: It is the SQL standard operator for string concatenation.  It should be ignoring `NULL` values -- but perhaps not all databases do that.

Comment: @DM Yes it does.

Comment: Everyone sorry for the stupid question :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`||` is the string concatenation operator.  You can't concatenate `null` to a string.

If you have a table `tbl`...

| id | col1 | col2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | a1 | a2 |
| (null) | b1 | b2 |

...and you ask...

```
select col1
, 'pilot' || cast(id as string) AS id
from tbl
```

...you'll get...

| col1 | id |
| --- | --- |
| a1 | pilot1 |
| b1 |  |

...because...

```
'pilot' || null
```

...returns `null`.

(You should specify which RDBMS you are using.)  This may not be true in Oracle because it treats NULL and '' as equivalent.  But it appears likely that `id` is an `int` field, so you may get the same results because of the `cast`.