# Adding a temporarily comma into a column without updating any tables

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two tables and have used a simple query:

```
SELECT * FROM innerb where not exists 
   (select * from wms where barcode = innerb.barcode) and pcode like '%102';
```

My results come out like this:

[image]

I need to add in a comma for all values so it looks like this:

[image]

But I don't want to update the table nor create a new table, just to add it in for few seconds.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could create a view:

```
CREATE VIEW innerb_comma AS
SELECT CONCAT(Pcode, ',') AS Pcode,
       CONCAT(Brand, ',') AS Brand,
       CONCAT(Pdescription, ',') AS Pdescription,
       CONCAT(Size, ',') AS Size,
       CONCAT(Barcode, ',') AS Barcode
FROM innerb
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM wms WHERE barcode = innerb.barcode) 
  AND Pcode like '%102';
```

Then select from that instead:

```
SELECT * FROM innerb_comma
```

[Demo on dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=7592116bcfbf60a3fef4da9c0dc19148)

Comment: What is a view? I can see I have a new view inside my SCHEMAS inside the navigator on the left hand side of the screen. And how would I drop it?

Comment: A view just allows you to create a different way of looking at the data from a table. You might for example sum some columns in it, or multiply one by another. It has no effect on your actual tables. You can remove it with `DROP VIEW innerb_comma`. See the [manual](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-view.html)

Comment: @Eduards I've corrected the view definition. Because you are trying to compare the `barcode` with the value in the `wms` table (which doesn't have a comma appended), the entire query needs to be in the view. I've also added a demo

Comment: He doesn't need the view, he can just execute the embedded SQL in that view definition, and it would return what he needs.

Comment: @LasseVågsætherKarlsen agreed. If OP needs to execute the query more than once the view makes it easier.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT pcode || ',' as pcode
     , brand || ',' as brand
  FROM table
```

EDIT: Only works on some DBs. Apparently not MYSQL(unless you configure it to work).
[What does SQL Select symbol || mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23372550/what-does-sql-select-symbol-mean) has a list of what works on which DB

Comment: `||` is an `OR` [operator](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/logical-operators.html#operator_or), how is this supposed to add comma?

Comment: Not in SQL. || is basically the same thing as CONCAT just shorter and in my mind, more readable. Might be different in different DBs, but I think its quite common.

Comment: I linked docs for MySQL in my comment, also tried in dbfiddle and it behaved like OR.

Comment: Seems that Oracle and PostgreSQL [support](https://www.oreilly.com/library/view/sql-in-a/9780596155322/re92.html) `||` as concatenation operator but OP uses MySQL

Comment: It would appear so yeah. Good list here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23372550/what-does-sql-select-symbol-mean

Comment: Accepted answer there states *mysql: concat ( vararg function ). caution: || means 'logical or'*. There's a note that you can configure MySQL to use `||` as a concat operator but by default it's an `OR` operator